# How to only output dependencies from latexmk?

Tags: latexmk, makefile

I'd like to use `latexmk` in a Makefile, so I've read the manual section on that.  However, the dependency generation step seems less than ideal.  Specifically, it seems that `latexmk` can only show dependencies after fully building an output file (which can take a long time in my case).  Is there a way to have `latexmk` only output dependencies to a file and not mark the actual output file as up-to-date?

I've tried the following rule in my Makefile, but it seems to mark the output file as up-to-date.  I'd also think it could run multiple times (or think it has failed) depending on what's in the log file.

```make
%.d: %.tex
    @echo "Generating $@ from $<"
    @set -e; \
     $(LATEXMK) -M -MF $@ -quiet -pdf \
      -pdflatex="echo Generating dependencies from %T" $<
```

Comment: This might be a problem as some of the dependencies arise only during compilation (like `tikz-externalize`, automatic `epstopdf` etc.). Even bibliography usage is actually known only during the compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@tohecz: You are correct.

The problem is that the dependencies depend in a complicated way on the detailed contents of the TeX file (and all the files it calls in, including the class file and the style files).  The only easy way to determine the dependencies is to run `pdflatex` (or `latex` as appropriate), and then analyze the resulting files (the relevant ones are the `.fls`, `.log` and `.aux` files).   If the `.tex` file changes, then both the `.pdf` and the dependency information are simultaneously out of date.

Therefore, if you want to run `pdflatex` to determine the dependencies, you get a new `.pdf` file as a side effect.  So there's no point to trying to update the dependency information without updating the `.pdf` file.

Comment: This isn't entirely true, though. If you employ `make` (e.g. GNU make) to build stuff only when things changed, it's `make` that needs to know the dependencies. The only alternative is to make your main `.tex` file a phony target (in GNU make lingo) in an attempt to have `latexmk` figure it all out on its own. But it means `latexmk` _always_ runs, even though it would not have to if `make` knew the "top-level dependencies".